# Ubuntu permissions: file owned by `mysql` can't be deleted by user that's a member of the `mysql` group

Tags: python, mysql, ubuntu

I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 and am slightly confused about permissions/group membership:

A MySQL query executes and writes a file to the `/tmp` folder. It's owned by the MySQL user:group :

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 mysql mysql     22399 Jun 28 12:17 /tmp/dump.csv
```

I added my user to the MySQL group:

```
sudo usermod -a -G mysql awoolford
```

If I run `id` I can see `mysql` listed in the list of groups:

```
awoolford@deepthought:~$ id
uid=1000(awoolford) gid=1000(awoolford) groups=1000(awoolford),4(adm),24(cdrom),27(sudo),30(dip),46(plugdev),117(lpadmin),118(sambashare),129(mysql)
```

I wrote a Python script that's executed as my user. It doesn't delete the file despite being a member of the `mysql` group, e.g.

```
awoolford@deepthought:~$ python
Python 2.7.6 (default, Mar 22 2014, 22:59:56) 
>>> import os
>>> os.remove('/tmp/dump.csv')
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
OSError: [Errno 1] Operation not permitted: '/tmp/dump.csv'
```

How can I programmatically delete this file without running the script as `sudo`?

Comment: Any particular reason you need a python script to rm? Also see http://superuser.com/questions/784952/linux-group-member-cannot-delete-file-with-rw-permission about permissions.

Comment: I'm using Python to do a bunch of ETL-type work (a MySQL-to-Neo4j migration), and the file deletion is part of that process. From the SuperUser link you sent, it seems that `/tmp` is a special case (despite having permissions of `drwxrwxrwt root:root` on the folder). So I should create another folder and not use `/tmp`?

Comment: Since only the owner can delete, if you can't arrange for the user you want to delete the file to own the file, then you may need to pick another location, yes.

Comment: Thats good info. Thanks for the advice. :)